# Cannot Run .NET C# Application Outside Debug Folder

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm having an odd issue with Visual Studio Community 2015. My program runs correctly inside the Visual Studio Editor, and it also runs correctly when the Application .exe is double clicked in the bin/debug/ directory. However, when the Application is run anywhere else on the computer (including the Release directory) the program does not run correctly. I am definitely copying all of the Debug folder to the location of attempted execution so it's not because of that.

When I run the executable, a loading icon appears on the mouse, in Task Manager it appears as a process using about  < 500K RAM and stays there until reboot. No window appears at all, and it is impossible to end the process once it has started, meaning it cannot be deleted.

I'm using .NET 4.5.2 primarily however I've tried 4.5 and 4.6 and neither fixed the issue (I've checked and I have all 3 of them installed). I also tried copying the System DLLs locally and that didn't fix the issue either. I also tried creating a minimalist solution (below) containing a project that only printed "Hello World" and quit.

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

This program experienced the same issues except it couldn't even be run within the Debug folder, only within Visual Studio. I then changed the project so it opened, then closed again straight away without printing anything so that it didn't use the System libraries at all, and it did the same thing. I then tried running the program in both 64 and 32 bit forced, (on a 64 bit laptop) and that didn't make a difference either.

I'm using Windows 7 Home Premium - Visual Studio Community 2015

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Do you get any errors in the event log?

Comment: Is there any configuration that need to be set in order the application to run ? you should only run you're application using the release configuration

Comment: @David I saw that advice listed on a similar question however I'm not sure where I need to be looking on Event Viewer

Comment: @Thomas What do you mean by configuration that needs to be set? When I tried to run the program after it was built to the release folder (as opposed to the debug folder) it hanged, as it would if I executed the program elsewhere on the computer

Comment: You should have a *.config file associated to your application, Do you deploy it also ?

Comment: @Thomas Yes, *everything* in the debug folder is copied to my deployment folder and it still hangs on execution

Comment: You need to define “does not run correctly”. We cannot diagnose this without code that illustrates the problem; try posting your “minimalist solution”.

Comment: @DourHighArch I have edited my question

Comment: @Apples292 it still isn't clear what happens when you try to run it... can you be **very explicit** about what happens?

Comment: @MarcGravell I've done my best, it's quite hard to explain nothing happening...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another possibility for such a rare issue could be your Anti-Virus program. Some of them like to inject an DLL into each created process to better protect you. But this can also lead to such awkward problems.

The only other way that comes to my mind would be to check the Event Viewer or run [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) to get an idea where the error comes from.

Comment: This was the issue, as soon as I disabled Avast, it worked... Is there anyway to stop it doing that in the future without disabling Anti-Virus?

Answer (score 2):

Try using the release configuration and enable Break on all exceptions (Check [Managing Exceptions with the Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x85tt0dd.aspx) for help on enabling the VS exception handling).

Hopefully this will break visual studio and show you enough information on the exception.

You can also try using [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) to find the issue.

I would highly recommend using a simple hello world program to find out the root cause. My suspicion is on some corrupt .NET framework installation

Comment: If you were intending for me to run it within Visual Studio after setting the config and enabled break on all exceptions then it didn't work I'm afraid

Comment: Unfortunately the process doesn't even show up in process monitor unless its run within Visual Studio. It's visible in Task Manager and Process Explorer, but not Process Monitor.

Comment: All the processes are available in process monitor. When you say it didn't work in VS, what exactly happened? Did it hit the first line of your code in main?

Comment: it didn't break at all when run inside Visual Studio, but it was an anti-virus issue the whole time

Comment: Glad you figured out the issue

Answer (score 0):

That's because it's not the proper exe...

In order to get a proper working .exe for you App Right Click on your project in Solution Explorer > Go to "publish" tab > select Publish Now

(Now go to debug folder and find exe)

It will automatically open the "publish" folder which has files for install, but NOW go to your "debug" folder and you will find the working exe there and some other Visual Studio generated files releated to publish that you don't really need

~ ChenChi